# Natural log of 0, or approximate it using limits

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics, indeterminate-forms

I have a forensics question that asks when a body will reach room temperature if left undisturbed. I am told room temperature is 20 degrees and I am working with Newton's Law of Cooling.

I have an equation:

$$y(t) = 11e^{-0.00265t} + 20$$

This tells me the temperature of the body at time $t$. I want to find the time when the body will reach room temperature.

Just for sake of example, say I want to find the time when the temperature is $25$:

$$\begin{align}
25 &= 11e^{-0.00265t} + 20 \\
(25-20) &= 11e^{-0.00265t} \\
5 &= 11e^{-0.00265t} \\
\frac{5}{11} &= e^{-0.00265t} \\
\ln{\frac{5}{11}} &= \ln{e^{-0.00265t}} \\
\ln{\frac{5}{11}} &= -0.00265t \\
\frac{\ln{\frac{5}{11}}}{-0.00265} &= t \\
297.531 &\approx t
\end{align}$$

Thus the body will reach $25$ degrees at time $t = 297.531$. This is fine and dandy but when I want to find $t$ when the temperature is $20$, I run into an issue:

$$\begin{align}
20 &= 11e^{-0.00265t}+20 \\
(20-20) &= 11e^{-0.00265t} \\
0 &= 11e^{-0.00265t} \\
\frac{0}{11} &= e^{-0.00265t} \\
0 &= e^{-0.00265t} \\
\ln{0} &= \ln{e^{-0.00265t}} \\
\text{Undefined} &= -0.00265t
\end{align}$$

Since $\ln{x}$ is only defined in $\mathbb{R}$ for $x \gt 0$.

My equation $y = 11e^{-0.00265x} + 20$ has a horizontal asymptote at $y = 20$. Is this a trick question or there is a solution that can be found using limits? I am familiar with limits with respect to $x$, but not $y$. I need something like $\lim_{y\to20} y = 11e^{-0.00265x}+20$ which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The body will never reach room temperature, according to your equation. However, in reality it depends on how accurate is the room temperature and the measurement of the body temperature. At some point you can't distinguish the two.

Comment: It will never reach room temperature with the ideal model you are using. In many engineering situations, one takes five time constants as 'close enough'. In your case, the time constant is $T={ 1\over 0.00265}$.

Comment: "Newton's law of cooling" says that at $t=0$ the temperature was 31. This is the body of what exactly? The interesting fact is that the number $e$ was introduced by Euler after Newton died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temperature is never $20$.  The exponential function is positive for all inputs, as is $11$, so $11\mathrm{e}^{-0.00265t}+20 > 20$ for all $t$.  In the limit of infinitely large time, the temperature approaches $20$, getting as close as one likes to $20$ after a sufficiently long time.